# How to publish and reveal Static Card from Glass GDK?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I updated Glass to XE12 today.
I'm fascinated by the addition of Static Cards API into GDK.

I was able to publish Static Card, but it doesn't focus automatically. 
User has to scroll to it.

Am I doing something wrong, or this is a limitation of GDK by now?

```
Card c = new Card(MyService.this);
c.setText(test1);
c.setFootnote(test2);
long lastCard = mTimelineManager.insert(c);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static cards currently only support the kind of silent background publishing that you are seeing now. Please file a feature request in our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) if you would like to see more capabilities like the ones you're describing.

Comment: Thanks, Tony. Filed a request: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=311